# Facebook Share Dialog with specific image?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to use Facebook Share Dialog on my website. It is essentially photo blog with plenty of photos. I want to give users ability to share specific photo on Facebook.

As far as I understand from reading FB API documentation, there is only option to

- Specify meta tag (og:image)
- Include in this meta tag one photo per URL

This doesn't work for my case, since I have many photos per page. And UI is around sharing special photo, not whole page.

Is there any other way? I need to specify, which photo user shares not from META tag, but from JS.

Comment: Use the feed dialog of FB this might suit your requirements. Refer: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

Comment: Specifying og:image is the only way. And why would you want to do it in any other way. If I see a share with an image I expect that image to be on the page that I get to when I click the link

Comment: @WizKid This doesn't work for my case, since I have many photos per page. And UI is around sharing special photo, not whole page.

Comment: @RohitBatra, sounds like a solution! I was clicking on "developers are encouraged to use the more modern Share Dialog, which can perform all of the same functions" — but could not find "picture" attribute inside its docs.

Comment: But if you share one image and then I get sent to the page that shows all images that is still a bad experience as a user

Comment: @WizKid You get sent to page with # anchor link to that specific image. But I see your point, it is really not a great experience.

Comment: Just make it a unique url instead like: example.com/albumid/photoid and when photoid is in the url you scroll down to the image. That way it is a unique url and you have no problem